# How to best set FFMPEG scenecut threshold

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, live-streaming

I am using FFMPEG to get live stream (from an ATSC receiver), and cut it into shots/scenes. Looks like there is a `scenecut` threshold (`20` in my example) that specifies the sensitivity for scene change detection. What is the best value to set for best shot extraction? I need the outputs to be a single scene/shot with best accuracy possible.

```
ffmpeg -i http://hts:hts@<IP ADDRESS>:<PORT>/stream/service/<HASH ADDRESS> -y -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -prese6t:v fast -deinterlace -x264opts min-keyint=15:keyint=1000:scenecut=20 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+skip_trailer+faststart /home/1/output%%05d.mp4
```

Comment: There's no definitive answer. I would expect that the developers set a default value (40) that they thought was optimal.

Comment: Yes, of course no definite answer. But maybe there are people with prior experiences have a good number in mind.

Comment: @Ariana I wouldn't rely on x264's `scenecut` for this purpose. You could do real-time content analysis with OpenCV. Take a look at [PySceneDetect](https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect) and adapt it for real-time usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, values `0.2 to 0.5` give good results. Below that, you start getting duplicate frames from the same shot as shot changes and above this, you start missing shot changes. Again, this is very subjective to the type of video, but any value less than `.15` produces a lot of unnecessary duplicate frames from the same shot.